# Linux History Detailed Information

Tags: linux, debian

I have a Linux Server and I'd like to know if is there a way to know who's connecting to my server, i mean; username, date-time, IP Address, what command did he/she used. I'd like to know if someone is copied information from my server to any external device (USB, mobile hard disk). Is possible to get all information I want on Linux (Debian)?
Managers connect to my server by ssh using winscp. On my Debian server i have a web server and database server (mysql and apache).
One thing i have noticed is that managers use root account, for that reason i need detailed information (ip-address, time, so on). I know this isn't the right way, but it's what i have right now.

Comment: How are they "connecting to your server"? HTTP? SSH? FTP? Physical keyboard? GIve us something to work with here. And why do you have this tagged Red Hat _and_ Debian? Which is it?

Comment: To connect to my server, managers use winscp, and in such server i have a web server and a database server, I'd like to identify any change or anything they are doing. The only thing i know is "history" command. but i need something more. As i mentioned upside, if someone copied information (when he did it, from what ip)

Comment: So... SSH, then? Also are we talking about logging the activity of normal, somewhat trusted users, or trying to trace a hack/attack/some kind of illicit access? Should we presume the users are leaving a trail or trying to cover their tracks? There's all sorts of questions here you need to narrow down to get a proper answer.

Comment: There's "last" on most systems which will let you see users who have logged in, from where, and for how long... unless you're attacker is using some sort of rootkit to cover their tracks.  This is kinda out of scope for stackoverflow btw.

Comment: Two-Bit,  i don't have anything more detailed for everything i detailed on my subject? (who copied information, what command did he drop off, ip address, time)

Comment: ... and if you know the username you might be able to view the account's history file (provided it has one) to see what commands were ran.  Getting more detail than that would require some additional setup ahead of time.

Comment: ok. First about i should use last? right?, they i should check the history account,how can i get the information about the ip-address, is that possible?

Comment: @CabezzCabezz You get the IP address differently for an SSH connection than for an HTTP connection than for an FTP connection, etc. You **have** to narrow down this question if you want an answer. Also, we're not going to be able to make you a security and diagnostics expert on Linux with some back and forth in this space. There are entire classes taught on the subject you're asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `auditd` daemon to track user activity on your server. Take a at the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/auditd) for more information.

Auditd requires some configuration. There are plenty of configuration examples on the net. You can check out [this security exchange Q&A](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4629/simple-example-auditd-configuration) for example.

However I'm not sure if `auditd` is capable of doing everything you require. I don't think you can track IP addresses for example.

You are probably better off creating separate accounts for all your users and using sudo for privilege escalation if needed. People can use DHCP, so tracking IP addresses might not help you to track down who did what on the system anyway.

Comment: Excelent information Knowhy. I'm gonna study about auditd. For now i need to track everything on local network.

Comment: @CabezzCabezz Good luck with your learning. Maybe [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) will help you, too. Just wanted to make sure you didn't take my trying to scope your question (for SO) as discouragement to your learning in general, which is laudable.